# Check if array of objects contains value from other array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following arrays of objects:
[image]

I need to check if these two arrays have the same `begin` property. In this case that appears to be true in three objects. So far I have tried this code, but with no luck (`input.value` being the first array).

```
const found = input.value.some((item) => item.begin === filtered.filter((time) => time.begin));
```

Any ideas how can I achieve this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you want only the count? please add the wanted result.

Comment: I want the output to be true/false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method.

```
const found = input.value.map((item) => filtered.findIndex((time) => time.begin === item.begin) > -1).findIndex((item) => item === true) > -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for the beginnings of `filtered` and check against the set without more iterations.

**Big O** of this is O(n), because of O(n) of creating the set and another `O(n)` of the check and beacause of adding two `n` you get O(n).

The other [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64857826/1447675) has because of the nested structure O(n<sup>2</sup>).

```js
const
    filteredSet = new Set(filtered.map(({ begin }) => begin)),
    found = input.value.some(({ begin }) => filteredSet.has(begin));
```

Comment: This works, I just like the one line solution better. Thank you though.